# Rails Page Cache with different domains pointing to same app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a same Rails app with many domains names and slight UI differences. Every domain may have different locales (en, es, fr, etc).

I use `caches_page` to cache all objects of `users` controller. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304404/471313) with a small modification to work with domains and locales instead of subdomains.

```
  def self.page_cache_path(path,extension)  
    MyApp::Application.config.action_controller.page_cache_directory + '/cache' + @root_site.to_s + "/" + path + extension
  end

  def cache_page(content = nil, options = nil, gzip = Zlib::BEST_COMPRESSION)
    path = [@root_site, I18n.locale].join("/") # nil would add slash to 2 ends
    path << case options
    when Hash
      url_for(options.merge(:only_path => true, :skip_relative_url_root => true, :format => params[:format]))
    when String
      options
    else
      if request.path.empty? || request.path == '/'
        '/index'
      else
        request.path
      end
    end
    super(content, path, gzip)
  end
```

This code seems to be writing cache files fine, placing the domain name as the first folder:

```
Write page /Users/user/Sites/myapp/public/cache/domain1.com/en/users/john.html (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK
```

The problem I see is that it is not retrieving the cache when I visit any cached page:

```
Started GET "/users/john" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-16 19:04:18 -0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
...
Write page /Users/user/Sites/myapp/public/cache/domain1.com/en/users/john.html (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK
```

On my `users` control I have simply this

```
caches_page :show
```

Anyone knows what is preventing to read from the cache file and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Rails to cache by hostname + serve the correct cache by hostname, then you should use `caches_action :show` instead. Cache will be stored in Rails.cache and served by Rails' own mechanism.

> Action caching uses fragment caching internally and an around filter to do the job. The fragment cache is named according to the host and path of the request. A page that is accessed at http://david.example.com/lists/show/1 will result in a fragment named david.example.com/lists/show/1.
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html

**However**, if you want to keep page caching and avoid Rails entirely when serving cached content, you should configure your *web server* to look for the static files in your customized path, by combining the hostname.

e.g. to cite [page_cache_fu](https://github.com/yeah/page_cache_fu) example of nginx conf

```
if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri/index.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1/index.html break;
}

if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1.html break;
}
```

I've not tested the above conf, but that's the idea. Same should be achievable on most webservers